# Can you add a non-square drop shadow to PNG content with CSS?

Tags: css, image, transparency, shadow, css-filters

Is it possible to do a drop shadow on the content of a PNG?

**Not a square**, but an object drop shadow that
acts on the non-transparent content of the PNG.

Comment: Probably better to do that in the PNG itself rather than do it in CSS.

Comment: Not so much "better" but it's just the only way. It *would* be cool if it was possible.

Comment: @Wesley: it's entirely possible with Super Duper Canvas Power™.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: To a .png? Have a link? I'd love to see it!

Comment: @easwee DX filters in IE CSS are an abomination to mankind.

Comment: @vcsjones They are still useful sometimes. And if you look it other way - MS did try to implement some CSS3 features that we only now can use years ago. To bad it never got more solid and optimized.

Comment: @Wesley: see my answer for an example.  Super Duper Canvas Power™ *is* Pretty Good Stuff.

Comment: @vcsjones: "better to do it in PNG" - true, but no fun :-)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

It's definitely possible.

**Using filters,** sample:

```css
img { 
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
    filter:         drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222); 
}
```

Comment: http://demosthenes.info/blog/600/Creating-a-True-CrossBrowser-Drop-Shadow-Effect-With-CSS3-&-SVG goes into some details about cross-browser functionality, since this is webkit-only (for now).

Answer (score 19):

It's not possible to do that in CSS. However, it's quite possible to do it through a canvas, but it will be somewhat inefficient (as it's processed by the client each time) and will be JavaScript dependent. Doing it in the PNG will be easier and will work on more browsers.

If you want more information about it, search the web for things like "html canvas blur" and "html canvas load image". Or better still, use the canvas shadow functionality which can do it all.

Here's an example: http://philip.html5.org/demos/canvas/shadows/various.html

- create context from canvas
- set `context.shadow(Color|OffsetX|OffsetY|Blur)` as desired
- load PNG from img tag with `context.drawImage`
- ah! the shadows!

And a bonus:

- use `context.toDataURL` if you want to export to PNG (make a web app which you drop PNGs in and it gives you shadows!)

Comment: That *is* some pretty cool stuff, albeit not a CSS solution. (+1 implied)

Comment: @Wesley: hah, CSS? Overrated. ;-)

Answer (score 12):

How times change. It's now possible [in some browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-filters), as shown in the currently accepted answer.

---

<strike>It's not possible to do this using CSS:</strike>

[image]

That's what I assume you're asking for.

Answer (score 7):

Until it will be available to CSS, you can try my approach.

My example uses this picture:

[image: original image]

because it has a transparent background and it isn't square (for CSS's box-shadow to get into action). It's not very fancy, but serves this small and simple tutorial fine.

Next step I took was to create another image, based on the one above, to place it under the original.

Step1. Add blur:

[image: blurred original]

Step2. Removed light and contrast:

[image: the shadow]

So I have the original and the shadow.

Next I will display it as if it is a shadow:

Style:

```
.common {width: 100px;height: 100px;background-size: 100% 100%; position:absolute;}

.divOriginal {background-image: url(../img/original.png);top:2em;left:2em;z-index:10;}

.divShadow {background-image: url(../img/shadow.png);top: 3em;left: 2.5em;z-index:8;}
```

Do the magic:

Add one div and set `attribute class="divOriginal common`" and another one with `class="divShadow common"`.

The result should be:

[image: result: pseudo-shadow]

Cheers!

Adi

Answer (score 3):

I've wrote a jQuery plugin for this, based on Chris Morgan's suggestion about canvas. You can find it on GitHub here: https://github.com/Kukunin/image-shadow

Comment: Great! And even with chrome fix!!

Answer (score 1):

Use createjs
sample can be found at
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eUqVm/1/)

```
shadowTarget.shadow = shadow;

stage.addChild(shadowTarget);

shadowTarget.x = 500 / 2;
shadowTarget.y = 450 / 2;

shadowTarget.regX = shadowTarget.image.width/2;
shadowTarget.regY = shadowTarget.image.height/2;
```