# Getting "square" box-shadow around transparent background PNG. How do I curve a css shadow around an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you add a non-square drop shadow to PNG content with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441332/can-you-add-a-non-square-drop-shadow-to-png-content-with-css)

Thanks for checking out my question.

Having an issue where by I am setting the hover of an image in css to have a box-shadow:
[image: example]

But the shadow is a square around the image, rather than following the path around the guy in the picture.

The image is a PNG-24 with a transparent background. Am I making a stupid mistake somewhere? Can this actually be done or do I need to somehow remove the square canvas from within Photoshop or swap out the image for the same one with a shadow via javascript?

Many thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: Not possible, you can use Photoshop, give a drop shadow to the image and on hover change that image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

its not possible with CSS. Use image sprite & change background position on hover.

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/2VkQN/)

Comment: Thanks, thought that might be the case.

Comment: @Christian Actually it is possible ;) Check Lea Verou examples: http://lea.verou.me/demos/css3-patterns.html